# In Java, how do I create a File from a String without writing it to disk?

Tags: java, string, file, type-conversion

I have some text in a String that I can't write to disk.  I need to pass it to a method which only accepts File as a type.  What would be the chain of conversions through which I could do this?  I imagine I start with ByteArrayInputStream, but where next?

Comment: File is an object that (more or less) describes a file location on disk that either exists or you want to exist. It isn't the file itself, as such it doesn't actually hold data

Comment: A way to do it would be to subclass File and override the methods that are internally called by the method. This sounds ugly though. Can you be more specific about which library are you using so you can only use that method that receives a File?

Comment: @morgano: The method that receives the File is from a third party for which we have little influence, not the source code.

Comment: "Ugly" doesn't even begin to describe this kludge.

Comment: If you must use this method, Write the data to a file and then access it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: The implementation disallows write access to create a file on the disk.

Comment: Why can't you write it to disk? It seems to me that if that method only accepts File, which is a path to a file on disk, you cannot guarantee the code will still work when there is no such file on disk.

Comment: Depending on the nature of the 3rd party code, you could attempt to expose private methods to get it to do your bidding without having to supply a file. This will likely get you into more trouble down the road though, I'd rather look for another library that is more suited to your needs.

Comment: Your question embodies a contradiction in terms.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that java.io.File does not provides any method to read from it, it's just a reference to a file in a file system, and it may not exist.

The method you are calling may just get the full address of the file using file.getAbsolutePath() and use that to open an InputStream.

If there's a method that receives an InputStream then you could send your ByteArrayInputStream.

Even if the method could receive an URL, then you could open up a little HTTP server and serve the data... But with a file it's kind of difficult.